# Decorators with access to original function

Tags: python, decorator

I have defined the following decorator:

```
def loop_callback(func):
    """Only works in programs with a single main loop. Can call .sameThread
    to access the original unwrapped function directly"""
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped_func(*args, **varargs):
        if mainThread==threading.current_thread():
            print("We are in the loop thread")
            func(*args, **varargs)
        else:
            print("In another thread")
            loop.add_callback(lambda: func(*args, **varargs))
    wrapped_func.orig=func
    return wrapped_func
```

The idea is that you should be able to access the original function by calling something like `myObject.myFunction.orig(arg1, arg2)`. Unfortunately, `orig` won't receive the self object, just `arg1` and `arg2`. Is there any way to fix this so that it can be called the way I want?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to figure out how to shoehorn it in to a decorator like this so that you actually end up with the bound method you want in the scenario you are talking about, but really, this is probably a great chance for you to learn about the [descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).